# $\mathbb Q[\sqrt{d}]$ has elements $α$ with negative norm $N(α)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, ring-theory

Assuming that $d$ is not a perfect square, for which integers $d$ the field $\mathbb Q[\sqrt{d}]$ has elements $α$ with negative norm $N(α)$?

Comment: The positive $d$.  The norm of $a+b\sqrt{d}$ is then $a^2 - b^2d$, and by picking, say $a=0$ and $b \neq 0$, you get an element with negative norm. If $d$ is negative, then you can see the form $a^2 - b^2 d$ is never negative.

Comment: @BarrySmith Is that it?

Comment: Is what what?  ..

Comment: @BarrySmith Is that the answer?

Comment: Yes.  Was the explanation unclear?  If $d$ is positive, there are such elements.  If $d$ is negative, there are not.